# Export File Name

Tags: dbeaver

When I'm exporting data in DBeaver i'm using ${table} and a number is now incrementing on the file name.

I have changed every setting out there that I"m aware of.  Tried different extensions.

I'm expecting TABLE.CSV and FILE.CSV and I'm getting TABLE_1.CSV and FILE_2.CSV.  What do I do to get the incremental number off so my python scripts can pick up specific table names.